# How to secure game API?

Tags: javascript, api, security

Let's say I want to create a simple, js, browser game for example, using phaser. Let's say that after playing game, the player will raise some points, that I want to put in python or php API.

My question is - is it possible to secure this?

Let's say that I have endpoint `api/points/?number_of_points=30/` that is secured through valid oauth token. The point is that as long as the game is written in js, the user can change number of points, and make API call with 120 points. He will be authorized because of token that is also visible for him. Is `uglify-js` the possible solution?

Comment: No, uglify-js will not prevent anyone from making HTTP requests to your server.

Comment: Btw, to send a highscore value you should use `POST` not `GET`